# How to get random number in JavaScript without repetition of same number and also at a specific range of number like 0 to 4?

Tags: javascript, function, loops

Currently I am building quiz app and I want to swap each options whenever the new question is come.

```
 [  {
        type: "multiple",
        difficulty: "medium",
        category: "Science &amp; Nature",
        question: "How old is the universe?",
        correct_answer: "13.8 Billion Years",
        incorrect_answers: [
          "4.5 Billion Years",
          "7.9 Billion Years",
          "16.2 Billion Years",
          "13.8 Billion Years"
        ],
      },
]
```

This is my code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    let questionNumber = randomQuestion();
    questions.innerText = quizArr[questionNumber].question;
    for(let i= 0; i<quizArr.length; i++){
        let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
        option[i].innerText = quizArr[questionNumber].incorrect_answers[randomNum];
    }
});



function randomQuestion(){
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * quizArr.length);
}
```

I want to swap each option inside `incorrect_answer` array.

Comment: Your question title typed into Google _verbatim_, could have already easily led you to the mentioned duplicates. Please show a minimum of reasonable effort, before you come asking.

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-sfu85y?file=index.js)